getting infinite re renders in a protected route when trying to navigate unauthorized users to the root path
I'm working on a React project where I have a protected route component (ProtectedRoute) that should only render its children if the user has a specific role (student). To achieve this, I'm using React Router and a context (AuthContext) to manage authentication and user roles. However, I'm encountering an issue with infinite re-renders in the ProtectedRoute component.
Project Overview:

The project uses React for the front end.
Authentication and user roles are managed using Firebase authentication and Firestore.
The AuthContext provides authentication-related functions like sign-in, sign-up, and fetching user data, as well as the user object and user role.
The ProtectedRoute component is responsible for rendering its children only if the user has the role of "student". If not, it should redirect the user to the home page.
Problem:

Despite several attempts to resolve the issue, I'm still experiencing infinite re-renders in the ProtectedRoute component. I've tried adjusting the dependencies in the useEffect hooks, but the problem persists.
Specific Issues:

The ProtectedRoute component seems to re-render infinitely, even after adjusting dependencies in the useEffect hooks.
The redirection logic based on the user's role (userRole) is not working as expected. Even when the user role is not "student", the children are still rendered instead of redirecting.
I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve the infinite re-renders in the ProtectedRoute component and ensure that the redirection logic works correctly based on the user's role.
protected route

import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { Navigate, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"
import { AuthContext } from "../context/contex"

const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const { user, fetchUserData } = useContext(AuthContext)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [userRole, setUserRole] = useState("")
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Fetching data")
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const userData = await fetchUserData(user.uid)
        setUserRole(userData.role)
        setLoading(false)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching user data:", error)
        setLoading(false) // Ensure loading state is set to false even in case of error
      }
    }

    if (loading) {
      fetchData()
    }
  }, [fetchUserData, user.uid])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("navigate effect", userRole)
    if (loading) return // Don't redirect while loading
    if (userRole !== "student") {
      navigate("/")
    }
  }, [loading, userRole, navigate])

  if (loading) {
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>
  }

  return children
}

export default ProtectedRoute


Fetch User Data

async function fUserData(userId) {
  try {
    const usersRef = doc(collection(db, "users"), userId)
    const docSnapshot = await getDoc(usersRef)

    if (docSnapshot.exists) {
      return docSnapshot.data()
    } else {
      return null
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching user data:", error)
    throw error
  }
}


Routes

<BrowserRouter>
  <AuthProvider>
    <Routes>
      <Route index="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route
        path="/private"
        element={
          <ProtectedRoute>
            <PrivatePage />
          </ProtectedRoute>
        }
      />
    </Routes>
  </AuthProvider>
</BrowserRouter>



I don't see any overt issues in this code you've shared other than index="/" is incorrect on the home route, it should be path="/" or just index. Nothing really that would create a render loop. Do you have any logic elsewhere in the app that redirects back to "/private" for some reason? Does How to create a Protected Route in React-Router-DOM help? See if you can create a running codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue you have that we could inspect live.

See if merging the second effect's logic into the first, just using the returned userData.role value directly to bounce the user off the route. What is the value of userData when this isn't working as expected?
